Using UseCompressedOops?
I observe some performance problems on switching from 32GB to 64GB memory for my appliction.
I have following configured:
java.arg.2=-Xms14g java.arg.3=-Xmx54g

From here
Compressed oops is supported and enabled by default in Java SE 6u23 and later. In Java SE 7, use of compressed oops is the default for 64-bit JVM processes when -Xmx isn't specified and for values of -Xmx less than 32 gigabytes. For JDK 6 before the 6u23 release, use the -XX:+UseCompressedOops flag with the java command to enable the feature.

So do I need to pass UseCompressedOops for my application?


So do I need to pass UseCompressedOops for my application?

No.
In fact, it won't work unless you tweak other things.  With 8 byte object alignment (the default), compressed Oops only works for heap sizes less than 32Gb.
There is an associated option -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes.  If you increase it from its default value of 8 to 16, you would then be able to use Oops with a 64GB heap.  (And so on.)
However, it is not clear that using Oops with the default object alignment will make your program faster, or significantly reduce its memory footprint.  And it is not clear if using Oops with a larger object alignment will help either.  The outcome will depend on your various aspects of your application and the only reliable way to find out will be to just try it and see.
It is also worth checking to see if the real cause of your poor application performance is not something else; e.g. using a Java heap that is too large relative to your system's physical RAM.
Reference:

Compressed OOPs in the JVM

You could also look at Compressed Class Pointers, which are another way to reduce an application's memory footprint.

I would not speculate whether reenabling compressed oops for 64 GB can compensate the higher memory consumption of 16 byte object alignment. I would simply try and measure. It’s worth noting that since Java 15, compressed class pointers and compressed oops are independent, so compressed class pointers could be used even with a heap > 32GB and default alignment.
